# Is Lotus Notes unable to display colors in HTML-mail precisely?

Tags: html, email, lotus-notes, newsletter

Currently I'm about to go crazy by trying to design a proper HTML-newsletter. Beside other problems I can't seem to get my desired background-color displayed correctly. I coded in #afbecd and it turns out as something like #b1b1d2. Is there any way to fix this? I'm using version 8.0.2

Comment: are you setting the style inline or via a stylesheet?  Try inline to see if that helps it be recognized.

Comment: Writing it inline I already figured out is the best solution for cross compliance, so I did that and even tried the old school markup attribute BGCOLOR but that doesn't help unfortunately..

Comment: Can you describe how you are testing this?  There are settings for each user in the Domino Directory that determine how inbound SMTP messages are handled.  They can be converted by the server from MIME to Notes rich text, or they can be left in MIME format, which leaves it up to the client to convert and display them.  The behavior in some cases is different.  Unfortunately, you can not control your recipients settings.  I understand that.  But it might be helpful to know more. Looking at the document properties of the received message can tell us a bit.  I.e., the data type of the Body field.

Comment: Hmm.. I took one of my test mails and right clicked to see the field informatinons -> MIME_Version. There it says version "1.0" and data type is "text". Does that help? I showed your comment to an computer scientist in our company, but he couldn't give an answer (but he doesn't seem a geek to me already :-) I start to believe Notes can only display web safe colors. Maybe it's better to close this question at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any reasons the HTML attribute "bgcolor" does not work in Lotus/IBM notes, when you prepend a sharp (#) to the hex color. So `bgcolor="#ff0066"` does not work. But `bgcolor="ff0066"` does. Fortunately this notation also works in all other mail clients.

Update: You can also write `bgcolor="#FF0066"` but the letters must be written in uppercase then.

Comment: Thanks for that! It works.. (Un)fortunately our Company will switch to MS Outlook in two weeks. So I simply can't care for the "Notes Group" anymore :-D

Answer (score 0):

Check the output code - did it remain as #afbecd?

If so, then it is an interpretation problem that you'd probably have to work around in Lotus notes. Try a slight variant of that color and see if you can get closer to what you want.

Lotus notes is only about 0.2% of most subscribe lists anyway, so unless you are sending to a special "Lotus Notes users" group, i'd suggest the "who cares" solution.

Comment: It's a considerably higher percentage of big corporate users, so anything targeted at people in big banks, etc., should be tested for Lotus Notes.

Comment: I agree on you, Richard. It is simply not an option to me to ignore this group... In the meanwhile I also tested slight variations of this color, still the same.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to export the mail in HTML format. Damn Fu**ing Notes!!!

Comment: @RichardSchwartz What is the highest % of Lotus users you've seen in a list recently?

Comment: I'm not in the mailing list business, so I couldn't tell you.  But for twenty years (until about a year ago), all my work was in and around Lotus Notes, dealing directly with the large enterprise customers that use it. I'm still involved, but less directly now, so I do know that there are some industries (e.g., financial services, pharma) where Notes has enough market share to care about.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the inline style with RGB color code.
Its `rgb(175,190,205)` for your hex `#afbecd`.

Comment: Oh... tried it this way (in both, bgcolor and style) and now it don't display any color anymore, it remains white.